# Which dataset used in jakeret/tf_unet U-Net implementation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am trying to implement U-net and I use https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet/tree/master/scripts this link as reference. I don't understand which dataset they used. please give me some idea or link which dataset i use.

Answer (score 1):

On their github [README.md](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet) they show three different datasets, that they applied their implementation to. Their implementation is dataset agnostic, therefore it shouldn't matter too much what data they use if you're trying to solve your own problem with your own data. But if you're looking for a toy data set to play around, check out their [demos](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet/tree/master/demo). There you'll see two readily available examples and how they can be used:

- **[demo_radio_data.ipynb](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet/blob/master/demo/demo_radio_data.ipynb)** which uses an astronomic radio data example set from here: http://people.phys.ethz.ch/~ast/cosmo/bgs_example_data/

[image: demo_radio_data.ipynb]

- **[demo_toy_problem.ipynb](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet/blob/master/demo/demo_toy_problem.ipynb)** which uses their built-in data generator of a noisy image with circles that are to be detected. 
  [image: demo_toy_problem.ipynb]

The latter is probably the easiest one if it comes to just having something to play with. To see how data is generated, check out the class:
image_gen.py -> GrayScaleDataProvider
(with an IDE like PyCharm you can just jump into the according classes in the demo source code)